# Running a server in a VM in Fusion on OS X..connecting externally?

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine

I'm running a piece of software listening on a particular port inside an Ubuntu VM using VMWare fusion on OS X.

I can connect to the port from OS X but I can't get to it via other, separate machines. I suspect that the OS X firewall is blocking access but I'm not sure how to verify that or really what port to open. I can't imagine there's a one to one port mapping from the actual machine to the VM.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Should be migrated to superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: Switch to bridged networking on the VM and it works :( It's always the small things that get overlooked.